# Time complexity and optimized way of a problem

Tags: python, greedy

I'm solving this [problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1253/C) in greedy way.
this is the code I wrote to solve the problem.

```
import math
n,m = map(int, input().split())

a = list(map(int, input().split()))

a_s = sorted(a,reverse=True)

res = []
for i in range(1,n+1):
    temp = i
    d = 1
    s = 0
    mid = a_s[-temp:]
    l = 0
    while(l<len(mid)):
        s += d*mid[l]
        l += 1
        if  l%m ==0 and l!=0:
            d += 1
    res.append(s)

print(*res,sep=' ')
```

Here I'm using loops for every value for `k` to calculate the value

I'm getting TLE for this solution. Can anyone help me to solve this problem in an optimised way?
I know that prefix sum is useful but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Python sum() sums the whole list. That can be useful for something like the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
n, m, q, a = 9, 3, 5, sorted([3,14,34,14,7,2,66,7,4], reverse=True)
print(*[sum([v*i+m+q for i, v in enumerate(a[-k:])]) for k in range(1, n+1)])

./eek.py 
8 18 31 48 72 103 148 207 300
```

Just replace the formula, `i+m+q` with something else and it might solve *C. Sweets Eating* ;).